# jQuery Convert string to url replacing brackets slashes and dash

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me with replacing this string into desired url link please?

```
1080 Center - (previously) Old/New
```

to

```
1080-center-previously-old-new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your single example (regex's shamelessly stolen from [Rails' `parameterize` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize):

```
"1080 Center - (previously)".toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\-_]+/g, "-").replace(/-{2,}/, "-").replace(/^-|-$/, '');
```

But it's hard to come up with a generalized solution without more example input and output.

That being said, you'll probably have an easier time if you come up with a precise specification for what you want to accomplish. For instance, at first it looks like the rule might be "Replace all non-word characters with dashes", but that would turn `Center - (previously)` into `center----previously-` which is not what you want. On the other hand, you can't just strip out whitespace, as that will lose the separation between `1080` and `Center`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can replace any non-word character with a `-` using a Regular Expression. Try this:

```js
var input = '1080 Center - (previously) Old/New';
var output = input.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks, but when I try '1080 Center - (previously)' it outputs '1080-center-previously-' np tho